# Alining text and Tikz image side by side

Tags: tikz-pgf

I can not align text on right side of the Tikz image.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\paragraph
$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&I_\Delta=\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap
\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\\
&\qquad \ \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\\
&\qquad ~ \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap
\end{aligned}
$
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in
 {2112/{( 1.8  , 1.1)}/{$z_1$}/right,
  1122/{( 0.1, 2.7)}/{$x_1$}/above,
  1212/{(-1.9 , 1.4  )}/{$y_1$}/left,
  1221/{(-2.7  ,-0.5)}/{$z_2$}/left,
  2121/{( 1  ,-0.8  )}/{$y_2$}/right,
  2211/{(-0.9,-2  )}/{$x_2$}/below
 }
  \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
\draw (1122) -- (1212) -- (1221) -- (2211) -- (2121) -- (2112) -- (1122);
\draw (1221) -- (2121) -- (1122) -- (1221);
\draw[dashed] (1212) -- (2211) -- (2112) -- (1212);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need minipages, but you do need to remove `\paragraph`, or add the default argument to `\paragraph`, i.e. `\paragraph{Heading}`. And you probably want `[baseline]` as an argument to the `tikzpicture` environment for vertical alignment. If you want to fine tune that, use `baseline=<length>`, where `<length>` can be positive or negative, e.g. `length=2cm`, or `length=-1cm`.

You do get an overfull box here, because equation+diagram is wider than the text block, so I scaled the diagram down a bit, with `scale=0.85`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\noindent$
\begin{aligned}[t]
&I_\Delta=\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap
\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\\
&\qquad \ \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\\
&\qquad ~ \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap
\end{aligned}
$
\hfill
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline,scale=0.85]
   \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in
 {2112/{( 1.8  , 1.1)}/{$z_1$}/right,
  1122/{( 0.1, 2.7)}/{$x_1$}/above,
  1212/{(-1.9 , 1.4  )}/{$y_1$}/left,
  1221/{(-2.7  ,-0.5)}/{$z_2$}/left,
  2121/{( 1  ,-0.8  )}/{$y_2$}/right,
  2211/{(-0.9,-2  )}/{$x_2$}/below
 }
  \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
\draw (1122) -- (1212) -- (1221) -- (2211) -- (2121) -- (2112) -- (1122);
\draw (1221) -- (2121) -- (1122) -- (1221);
\draw[dashed] (1212) -- (2211) -- (2112) -- (1212);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

use minipages:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[hmargin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \begin{align}
        &I_\Delta=\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap
        \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap \\
        &\qquad \ \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap\left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap \\
        &\qquad ~ \left<x_1,y_1,z_1\right>\cap
    \end{align}
\end{minipage}%
\begin{minipage}{.5\linewidth}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \foreach \n/\x/\l/\p in{
            2112/{( 1.8  , 1.1)}/{$z_1$}/right,
            1122/{( 0.1, 2.7)}/{$x_1$}/above,
            1212/{(-1.9 , 1.4  )}/{$y_1$}/left,
            1221/{(-2.7  ,-0.5)}/{$z_2$}/left,
            2121/{( 1  ,-0.8  )}/{$y_2$}/right,
            2211/{(-0.9,-2  )}/{$x_2$}/below%
        }{
            \node[inner sep=2pt,circle,draw,fill,label={\p:\l}] (\n) at \x {};
        }
        \draw (1122) -- (1212) -- (1221) -- (2211) -- (2121) -- (2112) -- (1122);
        \draw (1221) -- (2121) -- (1122) -- (1221);
        \draw[dashed] (1212) -- (2211) -- (2112) -- (1212);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
\end{document}
```

Note how I have commented out spaces: one in the head of the foor-loop and one between the minipages. The first caused an error, that the key `below`  is unknown (because of the trailing space). The second one would cause a linebreak between the minipages.

I have decreased the horizontal margins because otherwise it would not fit on one line.